# Creating table diagrams in MSSMS without the internal tool?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

My tables are based on MSSMS 2000 and I'm accessing them with 2008. (I also have VS 2005, 2008, and 2010)

The internal feature does not work with MSSMS 2000.

Please recommend a free third-party/opensource tool, **that will only read** and not install stuff on the DB server to create a visual display of a subset of the tables (columns, relations etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I bit the bullet and bought a full blown license for [ERStudio from Embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com/solutions/microsoft-sql-server) I used to use the [free version of Toad Data Modeler.](http://www.toadworld.com/Freeware/ToadDataModelerFreeware/tabid/637/Default.aspx)

It worked quite well, especially considering it's freeware.  I haven't used it since Quest took Toad over but Quest has a pretty good reputation in the biz.

Comment: I installed Toad but I can't make diagrams unless I have the license.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the wrong link.  I've updated my answer.  I meant to link to the Data Modeler tool.  Install that and use the "Reverse Engineer" feature to diagram an existing database.